# Whats wrong with my isNumber regex?

Tags: regex

why this function will return `"e10"` as `true`? (which is supposed to be `false`)

```
public boolean isNumber(String s) {
    String pattern = "\\s*[+-]?((\\d+.?\\d*)|.\\d+)(e[+-]?\\d+)?\\s*";

    return s.matches(pattern);
}
```

Comment: If @eavidan solved your problem, I'm sure he would appreciate if you accepted his answer by clicking the green checkmark. :)

Comment: ok didnt know that thanks man

Comment: No problem. You the man. :) (Notice that it also gave *you* a reputation boost, something we all enjoy. ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `((\\d+.?\\d*)|.\\d+)`. The second part means `.` - a matcher for anything, and `\d+` - at least one digit. 
If you meant to match an actual dot character, use `\.` instead.